How to prevent toast when unmounting a component?
I'm trying to prevent toast, when component unmount, if user click onSubmit. Trying to do with useState, but it didn't work for me.
My goal is to show user toast but if he click onSubmit, he shouldn't have to see this toast. Toast should have appears when component unmount and we go away from page with form without submit.
const [formSubmitted, setFormSubmitted] = useState(false);

const formik = useFormik({
onSubmit: async (values) => {
  setFormSubmitted(true);
  // some logic
  navigate('/toAnotherPage');
})}

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    if (formik.dirty && !formSubmitted) {
      toast({                                //toast from chakraUI
        description: "Save info to draft",
        status: "success",
        duration: 3000,
        isClosable: false,
        containerStyle: {
          fontSize: "16px ",
          fontWeight: "350",
        },
      });
    }
  };
}, [formik.dirty, formSubmitted]);


we go away from page with form without submit--> do you mean we change the path on the URL and hit enter? or is there a button to navigate to a different route?
Also, how does the toast look like? If a form is not submitted the user would be redirected to /toAnotherPage, no ? even if the toast IS rendered here, it would not be visible because the user would have already been redirected. is that correct?

Yeah, we not submited form and just go away, for example click on nav and redirected to another page. We can see toast only when unmounted component, when you leave route.

Can you try the below and let me know if it works?
       const [formSubmitted, setFormSubmitted] = useState(false);
        
        const formik = useFormik({
        onSubmit: async (values) => {
          setFormSubmitted(true);
          // some logic
        
        })}
    
    useEffect(()=>{
if(formSubmitted){
    // form was submitted, do not show the toast and redirect the user
    navigate('/toAnotherPage');
}
    },[formSubmitted]);
        
        useEffect(() => {
          return () => {
            if (formik.dirty && !formSubmitted) {
        console.log("use effect cleanup, showing toast now!!!");
              toast({                                //toast from chakraUI
                description: "Save info to draft",
                status: "success",
                duration: 3000,
                isClosable: false,
                containerStyle: {
                  fontSize: "16px ",
                  fontWeight: "350",
                },
              });
            }
          };
        }, [formik.dirty, formSubmitted]);


It works in second time, at the first time after navigation coming out two toasts ('Save info to draft').

The useeffect.cleanup.function is also called when the component mounts

I never used formik before but is formik.dirty true the first time?

Yeah, if your make some changes in inputs, formik.dirty become "true" and toast is working

I would not go with the clean up function in useEffect approach. Try going for the route changed solution.
Basically if route has changed and form is not submitted then render a toast message.
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const location = useLocation()

useEffect(()=>{
  if (formik.dirty && !formSubmitted) { 
   // your toast here
   }
// Listens for location path name change as well
},[location.pathname,formik.dirty,formSubmitted])

This should be able to fulfill your use case of issuing a toast message and notifying the user that their.

Unfortunately, this didn't work for me: if I leave the page, the toast won't appear, even if dirty=true

Did you try testing without dirty in the if statement. I am not sure what dirty does  and I have not used formlink before

Yes, I just tried it, but it seems to me that location doesn't work when the component is unmounted.
